# Detecting When A Scatterview item is inertial

Tags: wpf, scatterview

The ManipluationDelta event has the IsInertial property.
Unfortunately it appears that a scatterview item 'ManipulationDelta' event does not fire. Only its ContainerManipulationDelta event fires, but the ContainerManipulationEventArgs does not expose the IsInertial property.

So is there any other way to determine when a scatterview item is being manipulated via inertia?

Answer (score 0):

look at ScatterViewItem.AreAnyTouchesCaptured.   if that's false, then the item is being moved by inertia rather than by active touch inputs